# Fail getting specific XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a problem. I need to loop through a xml and get a specific data.
[image]

I need to get for each **`<API-MAPPINGS>`**  all **`<MAPPED-ARGUMENT-TYPE>`** and write them into a List.
I did like this:

```
 foreach (var typemapping in maplist.Elements("API- 
 MAPPINGS").Descendants("TYPE-MAP")) 
 {
     foreach (var mappedArguments in maplist.Elements("MAPPED-ARGUMENT-TYPE"))
        {
           newTypeMap.MappedArgumentType.Add(mappedArguments.Value);
        }
 }
```

But it's not working.
Can somebody tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change the second `maplist.Elements` to `typemapping.Elements`?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann Yes, it worked. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this may be a simple issue as pointed out by @SebastianHofmann. Inside your second `foreach` loop, you need to use the variable from the previous loop. See below for the updated loops:

```
foreach (var typemapping in maplist.Elements("API-MAPPINGS").Descendants("TYPE-MAP"))
{
    foreach (var mappedArguments in typemapping.Elements("MAPPED-ARGUMENT-TYPE")) //change this line
    {
        newTypeMap.MappedArgumentType.Add(mappedArguments.Value);
    }
}
```